# how do I get, parse and sum all the tds' of a table with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with an id "#stock-hotdogs" where the last column is always of the class ".subtotal". The subtotal is always on this format: $99.00 .  So what I need to know is how to get the numbers of all those td's, sum them and store them in a variable. What should be the way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
var cents_total = 0;

$('#stock-hotdogs .subtotal').each(function() {
    var value = $.trim($(this).text());
    var parts = value.substr(1).split('.');
    cents_total += +parts[0] * 100 + (+parts[1] || 0);
});
```

I don't use `parseFloat` here because one should not use float values for financial computations (rounding error). Should be trivial to convert the cent values to dollars :)

Comment: +1 This one will actually work because it takes care of the leading `$`, but why the `.split()` instead of using `parseFloat()`?

Comment: @patrickdw: Because of the rounding error in floating point arithmetic. At least this is what I learned here: Don't use float values for money ;)

Comment: Oh, gotcha. You're giving the result in cents. Good idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
var inputs = $('td.subtotal', '#stock-hotdogs').find('input');

var total = 0;

$(inputs).each(function() {
    total += parseFloat( $(this).val().replace(/[^\d\.]+/g, ''));
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/pXk8v/21/) is a live working example OR

A second version that isn't using input elements...

```
$('#totalbtn').click(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('td.subtotal', '#stock-hotdogs').each(function() {
        total += parseFloat( $(this).text().replace(/[^\d\.]+/g, ''));
    });

});
```

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/ChFL9/) is an example for this...

Comment: -1: `val()` will only work on form fields and `parseInt` will return `NaN` for text starting with `$`. Even if it worked, you are discarding the cents. *Edit:* I see, you assume that there will be input fields... the OP is not saying anything about this.

Comment: @Felix King, I understand what you're saying, I added a regex to fix that.

Comment: hello and thanks for your help @R-Tard, I'm trying to work my head around how could I make it work. [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hDCCt/) is what I'm trying to do... see, every time I change something, the total needs to change too. Any pointers on that? Right now the var shows NaN, and I'm not quite sure why

Comment: @la_f0ka: Seems to work quite well with my method: http://jsfiddle.net/hDCCt/1/ I suggest you cache as many elements as possible to not generate unnecessary overhead through finding the elements again. If one cannot change the price, you can even cache these values.

Comment: thanks, it does seem to work perfectly with your method, I just updated

Comment: @la_f0ka: The problem was that `parseFloat('')` (empty string) returns `NaN`. Whereas `+''` returns `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var subTotals = $('#stock-hotdogs td.subtotal');
var sum = 0;

subTotals.each(function() {
    sum += parseFloat($(this).text().substr(1));
});

alert(sum);
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/FishBasketGordo/f5V9P/

Comment: the td.subtotal's are actually being generated with jQuery too, depending on how many of each "kind" of hotdog you want. How can I use this so every time I change something in the inputs of class .qty the sum is updated and shown in #show-total ?

Comment: I'm actually using it like this http://pastie.org/2352865 but the result is "NaN". When I debug it, it seems to get the first value but then it changes to Nan

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var total=0;
$('#stock-hotdogs .subtotal').text(function(i,v){
    total+=parseFloat(v.substr(1));
});

alert('total: $'+total.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [JQuery Calculation](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/calculation/calculation.plugin.htm) plugin: it lets you specify which fields to sum using jQuery selectors. Using it you would do something like this:

```
$("#stock-hotdogs").find("td.subtotal").sum();
```